# Does anybody known the relationship between the $\Gamma (a)$ and $\Gamma (a+\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: gamma-function

Does anybody known the relationship between the $\Gamma (a)$ and $\Gamma (a+\frac{1}{2})$, is there a equation or approximate equality between this two?

Comment: One can get an asymptotic for $\Gamma(a+\frac12)/\Gamma(a)$ via Stirling's formula.